# Jquery separate result var

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery UI datepicker. The available dates are taken from a MySQL database, via json. It works OK.

From the selected date, I made a query to the database to retrieve a begin and end hour. The result is a variable named resp. The problem is that I need the date, the begin hour and the end hour each one on separate, and my actual result result is like this:

2018-06-1710:00:0014:30:00

How can I get separates variables?

Thank you very much for your help.

Te code is:

jQuery:

```
var js_array_dias = <?php echo json_encode($dias_entrega);?>;
var dayValues = js_array_dias.map(function(item){
                    return item.fecha_entrega
                                           });

  $(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var fechas_entrega = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                  return [ dayValues.indexOf(fechas_entrega) != -1 ]},
            onSelect: function(fecha_entrega) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'seleccion_hora.php',
                    data: {date : fecha_entrega},
                    success: function(resp){
                        if(false !== resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

seleccion_hora.php:

BEFORE:

```
echo $hora_inicio;
echo $hora_fin;
```

AFTER:

```
$fecha_entrega_viable=array('fecha'=>$fecha, 'hora_inicio'=>$hora_inicio, 'hora_fin'=>$hora_fin);
echo json_encode($fecha_entrega_viable);
```

Comment: Return JSON from your PHP with each date/hour value within its own property

Comment: Thank you very much, Rory. I made it. I updated the code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date and hours are always the same length (padded with zeros), this would work

```
//date and selected hours
myDate='2018-06-1710:00:0014:30:00';
    startHour=myDate.substr(10,2);
    endHour=myDate.substr(18,2);
    console.log(startHour,endHour);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, johnc. I made it via jsnon_encode on PHP